# How to get num results in mysqldb

Tags: python, mysql

I have the following query:

```
self.cursor.execute("SELECT platform_id_episode, title, from table WHERE asset_type='movie'")
```

Is there a way to get the number of results returned directly? Currently I am doing the inefficient:

```
r = self.cursor.fetchall()
num_results = len(r)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't actually need the results,<sup>*</sup> don't ask MySQL for them; just use [`COUNT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/counting-rows.html):<sup>**</sup>

```
self.cursor.execute("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE asset_type='movie'")
```

Now, you'll get back one row, with one column, whose value is the number of rows your other query *would* have returns.

Notice that I ignored your specific columns and just did `COUNT(*)`. A `COUNT(platform_id_episode)` would also be legal, but it means the number of found rows with non-NULL `platform_id_episode` values; `COUNT(*)` is the number of found rows full stop.<sup>***</sup>

---

<sub>* If you *do* need the results… well, you have to call `fetchall()` or equivalent to get them, so I don't see the problem.</sub>

<sub>** If you've never used aggregate functions in SQL before, make sure to look over some of the examples on that page; you've probably never realized you can do things like that so simply (and efficiently).</sub>

<sub>*** If someone taught you "never use `*` in a `SELECT`", well, that's good advice, but it's not relevant here. The problem with `SELECT *` is that it spams all of the columns, in random order, across your result set, instead of the columns you actually need in the order you need. `SELECT COUNT(*)` doesn't do that.</sub>